# Establish a landline call in C# using Tapi

Tags: c#, .net, modem, phone-call, tapi

I have been trying to make a calling application using C# that enables me to make a landline call from a PC with a modem.  I found ATAPI and TAPI but so far I was not enable to make a call with those libraries.  Can anyone give me sample code for just making a call and talk?
so far i have manage to find my modem but i am not able to receive the caller number or answer and make a full call(talking and receiving data)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using JulMar.Atapi;

namespace CompanyX_Libaray
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            TapiManager a = new TapiManager("test");
            a.Initialize();
            String modem = "Conexant USB CX93010 ACF Modem";
            TapiLine li=null;
            TapiLine[] l = a.Lines;
            foreach (TapiLine line in l)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line.ToString());
                if (line.ToString().Equals(modem))
                {
                    li = line;
                    break;
                }
            }
            li.Open(MediaModes.DataModem);
            //li.Ringing += new EventHandler<RingEventArgs>(li_Ringing);
            //li.CallInfoChanged += new EventHandler<CallInfoChangeEventArgs>(li_CallInfoChanged);
            //li.Changed += new EventHandler<LineInfoChangeEventArgs>(li_Changed);
            li.NewCall += li_NewCall;
        }
        static void li_NewCall(object sender, NewCallEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Call.CalledName);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Call.CalledId);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Call.CallerId);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Call.CallerName);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Call.CallData);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Call.Address);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Call.ConnectedId);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Call.ConnectedName);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Call.RelatedId);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Call.Id);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Call.CallOrigin);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code you tried? What errors did you run into?

Answer (score 0):

If you interested in Dial Command you should do the following steps: -

- Find the line
- Open the line in supported mode
- Do MakeCall command

  li.MakeCall(dialNumber);